# HTML tag nesting problems

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the code

```
- var list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
.navbar.clearfix
  a.logo(href="#") Logo
  div.links
    each i in list
      a(href="#")= 'Link ' + i
        .sub-menu
          each i in list
            a(href="#")= 'Link ' + i
```

The problems are the .sub-menu is not in the a element, and there is an extra blank 'a' in .sub-menu.

Is it possible to create a multi level iteration in pug? Thanks

Comment: An interesting related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965/is-putting-a-div-inside-an-anchor-ever-correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some restrictions of what you elements you can put inside of some elements. You can't have a `div` inside of a `p` element.

This is to ensure the markup remains as semantic as possible. Who would need a DIV element inside of a PARAGRAPH? Even in the general sense we don't see any meaning of having a `div` in a `p`, `div` is a block level element and `a` element can only contain elements which are not initially block elements. I've interestingly found that you can have 1 level of nesting of DIV in an anchor element and it will work, but other than that it will break.

Use `span` element inside of an anchor element and then use CSS to make it a block level element, the nesting should work completely fine with `span` inside of an anchor element.

This document may be helpful in understanding which elements plays well with which ones - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Flow_content

Answer (score 1):

HTML forbids nesting interactive elements. You cannot place a link within another link.

The tranditional markup for a series of menus with submenus is nested lists:

```
<ul>                  <!-- Top level menu -->
    <li>
        <a href="...">     Top level link </a>
        <ul>          <!-- Sub menu -->
            <li>
                 <a href="..."> Sub menu link </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: why does HTML forbid nested interactive elements? are there usability problems?

Answer (score 0):

I've found that this is not an issue of pug, but behaviour of browsers.

code like this

```
<a>11
  <div>22
    <a>33</a>
  </div>
</a>
```

won't nest as expected. At the moment, I replace tag a with div and emulate links with css. Still curious about this.